# How to pass row data as parameter in easy ui datagrid formatter function

Tags: jquery-easyui

How to pass row data as parameter in easy ui datagrid formatter function ?
For example:

```
<table id="dg"></table>
$('#dg').datagrid({
    url:'datagrid_data.json',
    columns:[[
        {field:'code',title:'Code',width:100},
        {field:'name',title:'Name',width:100, formatter: formatName},
        {field:'price',title:'Price',width:100,align:'right'}
    ]]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending few time i found solution as below :

Change function:

```
function formatName(val,rowObject,rowIndex) {
 if(val === 'E') {
     return "Export";
 } else if(val === 'I') {
     return "Import";
 }
 return val;  
}
```